# Palindrome Missing Alphabet issue in C

Tags: c, palindrome

I wrote a code to find out the missing palindrome alphabet in a string. It passes a few test cases and fails a few.

I'm not sure where I made a mistake and everything seems right in the code.

The code is,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char palindromeChar[100];
    fgets(palindromeChar, 100, stdin);
    int revCtr = strlen(palindromeChar) - 1, fwdCtr = 0, counter;
    for(counter = 0; counter < strlen(palindromeChar)/2; counter++) {
        if(palindromeChar[fwdCtr] != palindromeChar[revCtr]) {
            printf("%c", palindromeChar[fwdCtr]);
            break;
        }
        ++fwdCtr;
        --revCtr;
    }

}
```

When it comes to inputs like,

```
malayaam
```

It prints out,

```
m
```

which is the first character in the case, but what the actual condition is if the forward character is not equal to the reverse character, it's asked to be print.

Why does it prints the first character itself?
What's the problem and the fix?

Comment: Looks like the perfect time for you to learn to use a debugger to step through the code. It's a very short block of code, and a minimal sized loop. Can't get a much better learning opportunity than that IMO.

Comment: I tried my best.. But I don't understand what the problem is.. It still feels like the correct solution even when I use my paper and pen.. But there's an issue which I can't figure. ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fgets() includes the newline char '\n' in the array, so you need to skip that character.

```
int revCtr = strlen(palindromeChar) - 1
```

to

```
int revCtr = strlen(palindromeChar) - 2
```

Good point in the comment below about double checking for newline char first, so instead, leave revCtr as is and

```
    int revCtr = strlen(palindromeChar) - 1, fwdCtr = 0, counter;
    if (palindromeChar[revCtr] == '\n') {
        revCtr--;
    }
```

Comment: But you should probably test for the presence of a `'\n'` before choosing which to use. (in case the user entered a `99`+char string.)

Comment: And now another problem arises, it solved my problem, Now it shows up another error for inputs like 

**animallotsfoliateddetailofstoollamina**
for which the output should be `o` but it prints `t` which is supposed to be done as per the code. But I want the one which is not present to be printed out how can I change my code that prints out the one which is not present?

Comment: It is working correctly as you have it programmed so far, it tells you when corresponding letters do not match.  To do what you ask above requires additional code logic, which you will need to define carefully before implementing.  You basically need to accept half of the palindrome as the correct string and then 'fix' the other half to match it.  Which half do you accept as correct?  Do you want to fix the other half by overwriting or by inserting?

Comment: I fixed it :) Thanks :) I took the count of both the unequal letters and made a modulo operation and printed the character which had an odd count.. It worked!

Comment: Ahh, yes, that is a good approach to determining if a word is a palindrome.  Just keep in mind, it is allowed to have one char with an odd count, if it is the middle char.

Answer (score 2):

Try printing  {palindromeChar[revCtr]} as well, when you are using the break. It will help you to see the mismatched characters from front and end.